# Typescript method which always returns own type / "type X not assignable to type this"

Tags: typescript, typing

I'm trying to write a method which always returns the type it's called on. I've found the "this" type which allows something similar, but it appears that it is only compatible with the literal "this", and not with other instances of the same class.

```
abstract class A {
    // I need a method which always returns the same type for a transformation method,
    // a clone function would need the same interface
    abstract alwaysReturnSameType(): this
}
class B extends A {
    x:number
    constructor(x:number) {
        this.x = x
    }
    alwaysReturnSameType():this {
        return new B(this.x + 1) // ERROR: Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'this'.
        // this works, but isn't what I need: return this
    }
}
```

I've looked at some very long issues on github (e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) but I'm not sure if there's a solution to be found there.

Is there a way of solving this or should I just cast to supress the error, i.e. `return <this> new B()`

Comment: I don't think you can use the keyword **this** as a type.

Comment: @toskv See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html "Polymorphic this types"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast it to `this`:

```
class B extends A {
    x: number;

    constructor(x: number) {
        super();
        this.x = x
    }

    alwaysReturnSameType(): this {
        return new B(this.x + 1) as this;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20I%20need%20a%20method%20which%20always%20returns%20the%20same%20type%20for%20a%20transformation%20method%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20a%20clone%20function%20would%20need%20the%20same%20interface%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20alwaysReturnSameType()%3A%20this%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(x%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alwaysReturnSameType()%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20B(this.x%20%2B%201)%20as%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

I'm not sure why it doesn't work without it.

---

It actually makes sense that it complains about returning a `new B`.
When you declare that you return `this` it means "the current instance", but a new instance is different.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile because it doesn't work in the presence of other classes (which can't be proven to not exist).

```
class B extends A {
    x:number
    constructor(x:number) {
        this.x = x
    }
    alwaysReturnSameType():this {
        return new B(this.x + 1) // ERROR: Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'this'.
        // this works, but isn't what I need: return this
    }
}

class C extends B {
    constructor() { super(3); }
    foo() { }
}

let x = new C();
let y = x.alwaysReturnSameType(); // y: C, but it's a B
y.foo(); // fails
```

If you want to return `this` you'll need to `return this;`, or do more complex stuff to figure out how to dynamically determine your own constructor function from the class instance and invoke it correctly.

Comment: That does make sense, although the compiler could always output an error when it detects an extending class hasn't overridden the method correctly. I'm just going to cast to this, far less of a hassle than dragging a type parameter through every single use of the class.